# Shrink dimensions of gif as part of animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, animated-gif

Trying to find out if it's possible to 'shrink' an animated gif.  Not in file size but in regard to the dimensions of the image.

If not, is there any way to catch the animation with jquery/javascript so I can shrink the size my moving the image out of view with css?

Or alternately after there any libraries out there for simple image manipulation type stuff for HTML5 Canvas?

EDIT:
The first mock up of the image is at http://swmohappening.info/.  It's essentially a website that I'm doing to help out a local youth group retreat.

I'm wanting to shrink the portion of the letters that run-on so it's a more manageable banner to leave on the page.  I do need to maintain the dimensions of the center/main section of the image.

Comment: You might be disappointed in the result... GIFs do not seem to scale very well.

Comment: @elclanrs not much to be honest I don't know much about animated gifs besides the quick search I did on here and on google that all seemed to be talking about file size re-size and not dimensions...

I don't personally like gifs due to such limited color palette, but was just looking at all options.

The other think I had considered since posting question is doing a series of png/jpg images and using a jquery cycle pluggin to loop through them in order to animate them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what I've read makes it seem as though the jquery animate will simply change the dimensions of an image (which isn't what is needed at the moment).  I think I'll most likely end up using animate to move the image out of view to 'shrink' it that way...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function in jQuery - you can change the size of an image and specify the time that takes too.

Comment: from what I'm reading this won't actually re-size the image it will scale the image with css correct?  Which would throw off the image appearance.  Basically the image I'm working with is at http://swmohappening.info/  I'm wanting to shorten the image and remove the run-on portion of the letters while maintaining the width and the dimensions of the center/main section of the image.  It's kinda looking like a series of jpg's are going to be the answer and using a cycle pluggin

Comment: I do think I might be able to use this to give appearance of animation, but just not change the size of the image, but the div that I house it in and hide the overflow correct?  I'm still 'fairly' green with javascript I can get it done but it's generally a cluster :)